# Can't connect Analysis service in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, business-intelligence

I'm trying to connect to Analysis service by Clicking on DATA > From Other Sources > From Analysis Service but then error shows up. It's telling me that I have typed wrong server name. But connect to Database engine is fine, how do I do it ? Please help, this will be very helpful.

PS. I'm using SQL Server 2012 with tools. I use the same server name with database engine.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is installed locally you can try using "localhost" or just a simple dot ".". Make sure to connect to SSAS using SSMS and check in Properties > Security what are the users allowed to connect.

If you have multiple instances installed on the same machine then make sure you use the correct name with domain included: Domain\InstanceName

Another option is to check using the SQL Server Configuration Manager what are the network protocols activated.